# How/where to pass params from a view to a controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I'm new to PHP and Codeigniter; I did a login page without using Codeigniter, and it worked. Now I'm trying to do it under the MVC design and Codeigniter.

I have a controller which directs to the view of the login page. Then I submit - but I don't understand how and where to send the user name and password I got, to handle it.

I know it should be sent to a controller - but i don't understand how.

Should i just do this in my login view?

```
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="/controllers/checklogin.php" id='loginForm' dir="rtl">
```

Is there a better - or more elegant way to pass the params for a controller that will handle the login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In codeigniter, when a user is seeing the page generated by the view, they aren't directly accessing the view file. Instead they are accessing the controller which is rendering the view.  When you are taking POST and GET variables in, you should post them to the controller (which should handle all validation and error handling).

Here's an example I think is easy to follow:

http://jrtashjian.com/2009/02/simple-login-form-with-codeigniter/

Comment: i just realized that the only thing i needed is to move all the params with POST/GET back to the controller's function which handles all the authetication... :)